# Why is clang AST output saying `isInvalid` and not having the correct AST nodes for this function?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/b191305b101337182093f54ef6225930) showing a 400+ line long JSON AST node from the output of this command:

```
MAXMDIM=4 clang++ -Xclang -ast-dump=json hyperpoint.cpp > hyperpoint.json
```

It reads the `hyperpoint.cpp` file, which is also in the gist. At line 1799 there is this function:

```
EX ld det(const transmatrix &T)
{
  if (MDIM == 3)
    return det3(T);
  else
  {
    ld det = 1;
    transmatrix M = T;
    for (int a = 0; a < MDIM; a++)
    {
      int max_at = a;
      for (int b = a; b < MDIM; b++)
        if (abs(M[b][a]) > abs(M[max_at][a]))
          max_at = b;

      if (max_at != a)
        for (int c = a; c < MDIM; c++)
          tie(M[max_at][c], M[a][c]) = make_pair(-M[a][c], M[max_at][c]);

      if (!M[a][a])
        return 0;
      for (int b = a + 1; b < MDIM; b++)
      {
        ld co = -M[b][a] / M[a][a];
        for (int c = a; c < MDIM; c++)
          M[b][c] += M[a][c] * co;
      }
      det *= M[a][a];
    }
    return det;
  }
}
```

Stripping the line/column information from the AST JSON, it starts like this:

```
{
  "kind": "FunctionDecl",
  "isInvalid": true,
  "name": "det",
  "mangledName": "__ZN2hr3detERKi",
  "type": {
    "qualType": "hr::ld (const int &)"
  },
  "inner": [
    {
      "kind": "ParmVarDecl",
      "isInvalid": true,
      "name": "T",
      "mangledName": "__ZZN2hr3detERKiE1T",
      "type": {
        "qualType": "const int &"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "CompoundStmt",
      "inner": [
        {
          "kind": "IfStmt",
          "hasElse": true,
          "inner": [
            {
              "kind": "OpaqueValueExpr",
              "type": {
                "qualType": "bool"
              },
              "valueCategory": "prvalue"
            },
            {
              "kind": "NullStmt"
            },
            {
              "kind": "CompoundStmt",
              "inner": [
                {
                  "kind": "DeclStmt",
                  "inner": [
                    {
                      "kind": "VarDecl",
                      "isUsed": true,
                      "name": "det",
                      "mangledName": "__ZZN2hr3detERKiE3det",
                      "type": {
                        "desugaredQualType": "double",
                        "qualType": "hr::ld",
                        "typeAliasDeclId": "0x7fecda373f30"
                      },
                      "init": "c",
                      "inner": [
```

None of this looks correct, but this is mapped to like 1799.

- The param `T` is not `const int &` it is `const transmatrix`.
- The first `if` statement is `if (MDIM == 3)` not something unknown or `null`.
- etc.

What is happening here? What did I do wrong, what am I missing? Why isn't it giving the full correct output, and how do I get it to give the correct output? Also, is `isInvalid` there in the AST any hint?

You can try running that command for yourself, using the gist C++ file as input. You might have to get the whole [repo](https://github.com/zenorogue/hyperrogue/blob/02e8dec195cb8f9054f0d2efee651974d0c05c6f/hyperpoint.cpp) to let the C++ compile, but that is a quick download.

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is this command `MAXMDIM=4 clang++ ...`. That sets the value of the shell environment variable `MAXMDIM`, which has nothing to do with the compilation. If you want to predefine the C++ preprocessor macro `MAXMDIM`, you need to do so via a command line option: `clang++ -DMAXMDIM=4 ...`.

Comment: Also, I didn't read through that very long C++ file, but I do know that Clang uses `int` when it doesn't know what the correct type is, which could happen if `transmatrix` is undefined or incomplete. (And it could be incomplete because a member array variable uses an undefined dimension.)